# Setup Docker Jenkins with default plugins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to create a Jenkins based image to have some plugins installed as well as `npm`. To do so I have the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jenkins:2.60.3
RUN install-plugins.sh bitbucket
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm --version
USER jenkins
```

That works fine however when I run the image I have two problems:

- It seems that the plugins I tried to install manually didn't get persisted for some reason.
- I get prompted the list of plugins I want to install but I don't want to install anything else.

Am I missing anything configuring the Dockerfile or is it that what I want to achieve is simply not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing the contents of `install-plugins.sh`, I can't comment as to why the plugins aren't persisting. It is most likely caused by an incorrect installation destination; persistence shouldn't be an issue at this stage, since the plugin installation is built into the image itself.

As for the latter issue, you should be able to skip the installation wizard altogether by adding the line `ENV JAVA_OPTS=-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false`
 to your Dockerfile. Please note that this can be a security risk, if the Jenkins image is exposed to the world at large, since this option disables the need for authentication

EDIT: The default plugin directory for the Docker image is `/var/jenkins_home/plugins`

EDIT 2: According to the README on the Jenkins Docker repo, adding the line `RUN echo 2.0 > /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state`should accomplish the same thing

Comment: Thanks for this! The script is taken from the Jenkins github site: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/install-plugins.sh

Comment: I didn't realize it was a provided solution; it should be working just fine in that case.

Try rebuilding the image with the new ENV line, and see if that will solve the problem.

Comment: Also, if you wouldn't mind, could you make the answer the accepted one?

Comment: What I think it could also be happening is that the plugin gets installed (I get the log with it and the dependencies installed as well) but the fresh configuration wipes out the entire folder - just a guess. Re the second answer I will give this a go. In essence what I’m trying to achieve is to create an image with the users I need, plugins and Jenkins files all at once but not sure if that’s possible

Comment: According to the README on the Jenkins Docker repo, adding the line `RUN echo 2.0 > /usr/share/jenkins/ref/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state` may help.

The documentation states that this will prevent the prompt for plugin installation; I have not tested this myself however.

Comment: As for preconfiguring, this article has the right idea: https://blog.nimbleci.com/2016/10/11/how-to-deploy-jenkins-completely-pre-configured/. The main takeaway here is to copy out configuration files after you have gotten Jenkins to the desired state. Since you are using docker, just use the `docker cp` command to extract the config files from the image after all is said and done.

Answer (score 0):

Things have changed since 2017, when the last answer was posted, and it no longer works. The current way is in following Dockerfile snippet:

```
# Prevent setup wizard from running.
# WARNING: Jenkins will start with security disabled, without any password.

ENV JENKINS_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"

# plugins.txt must contain the list of plugins to be installed
# (One plugin per line, e.g. sidebar-link:1.11.0)

COPY plugins.txt /tmp/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /tmp/plugins.txt
```