# Create docker image with latest jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile

I'm using the latest Jenkins image (2.60.3) and then I would like to update the `jenkins.war` file that is in `/usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war` to get an image with the latest version of it (2.73.3). I'm trying to achieve that using the following dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins:latest
COPY jenkins.war /usr/share/jenkins/
```

I have the jenkins.war file in the same folder than the dockerfile. The issue I'm having is that for some reason the file doesn't get overwritten (there is the jenkins.war v2.60.3). Why that could be happening?

Comment: that docker image is deprecated. Why don't you use the jenkins/jenkins repository?

Comment: I didn't realize it at first, but my answer below also answer your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/q/47185493/6309

Comment: It does indeed. I have just tried this:

FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.73.3

# Skip setup wizard
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"

USER root
RUN addgroup --system --gid 581 dtpdkr && \
    adduser jenkins dtpdkr
USER jenkins

# Install plugins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh $(cat /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt | tr '\n' ' ')

to see whether I can get skip the wizard screen but I still get prompted for the plugins to install. Is it because I need to define all the admin stuff still?

Comment: That is possible, yes. I never saw that prompt with my Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, using the [jenkins/jenkins image](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/), I have (with the [latest LTS](https://jenkins.io/changelog-stable/)):

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.73.3

ARG http_proxy
ARG https_proxy

# Skip setup wizard
ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Djenkins.install.runSetupWizard=false"

USER root
RUN addgroup --system --gid 581 dtpdkr && \
    adduser jenkins dtpdkr
USER jenkins

# Remove executors in master
COPY master-executors.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/
# Set proxy based on proxy-password secret
COPY set-proxy.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/
# Create admin based on secrets jenkins-adm-name and jenkins-adm-pass
COPY security.groovy /usr/share/jenkins/ref/init.groovy.d/security.groovy

# Install plugins
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/install-plugins.sh < /usr/share/jenkins/ref/plugins.txt
```

That does give me an installed Jenkins LTS image, with all the plugins I need.

Since I am behind a proxy, I had to configure it first:

```
$ more set-proxy.groovy

import hudson.model.*;
import jenkins.model.*;

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

final String name = "proxy.mycompany.com"
final int port = 8080
final String username = "unix_web_account"
def password = new File("/run/secrets/proxy_password").text.trim()
final String noProxyHost = "127.0.0.1,localhost,mycompany.com"

final def pc = new hudson.ProxyConfiguration(name, port, username, password, noProxyHost)
instance.proxy = pc
instance.save()
pc.save()
println "Proxy settings updated!"
```

And I need to define an admin account:

```
$ more security.groovy

#!groovy

import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.security.*
import jenkins.security.s2m.AdminWhitelistRule

def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()

def user = new File("/run/secrets/jenkins-adm-name").text.trim()
def pass = new File("/run/secrets/jenkins-adm-pass").text.trim()

println "Creating user " + user + "..."

def hudsonRealm = new HudsonPrivateSecurityRealm(false)
hudsonRealm.createAccount(user, pass)
instance.setSecurityRealm(hudsonRealm)

def strategy = new FullControlOnceLoggedInAuthorizationStrategy()
instance.setAuthorizationStrategy(strategy)
instance.save()

Jenkins.instance.getInjector().getInstance(AdminWhitelistRule.class).setMasterKillSwitch(false)

println "User " + user + " was created"
```

Finally, I don't want any job execution on the master:

```
$ more master-executors.groovy

import hudson.model.*;
import jenkins.model.*;

println "--> disabling master executors"
Jenkins.instance.setNumExecutors(0)
```